# How to fire links with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fire a link if the `div` around gets clicked.

This is the general logic:

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  $("div a").click();
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

div:active {
  background-color: blue;
}

div a {
  pointer-events: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London">London</a></div>
<div><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London">Paris</a></div>
<div><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London">Almaty</a></div>
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. I think I would need the different `href` as variable or something like that. For now, probably all links would be fired at the same time, and not only the belonging one.

How is it possible to do that?

Would be thankful for help! <3

Comment: that is going to click every link

Comment: Just make the link fill up the entire div...

Comment: href for the all three link are same **https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code would work, you would end up clicking every link that is in side of a div. It is not going to just click the link in the div you are in. So first thing you need to do is select the link in the div you clicked.

After that, you need to trigger click on the DOM element, not the jQuery object. When you trigger it on the jQuery object, it only triggers the click event listeners you bound to it.

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  $(this).find("a").get(0).click();
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

div:active {
  background-color: blue;
}

div a {
  pointer-events: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London">London</a></div>
<div><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London">Paris</a></div>
<div><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London">Almaty</a></div>
```

Or just make the anchor take up the whole div so you do not need JavaScript at all.

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
}

div:active {
  background-color: blue;
}

div a {
  padding: 20px;
  display :block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London">London</a></div>
<div><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London">Paris</a></div>
<div><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London">Almaty</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `<a>` of the clicked div by selecting the first `<a>` children of the `this` clicked element.

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  $(this).children('a')[0].click();
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

div:active {
  background-color: blue;
}

div a {
  pointer-events: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London">London</a></div>
<div><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London">Paris</a></div>
<div><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London">Almaty</a></div>
```

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: @MartinZeitler I downvoted you and your answer is wrong and this answer is not a copy...

Comment: It has exactly the same problem as the question.

Comment: @MartinZeitler please refrain from that kind of assumption

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to the elements you are clicking, and in the "onclick" callback, select the `a` element and click it.

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("div")).forEach(e=>{
    e.addEventListener("click",(el)=>{
        el.target.querySelector("a").click()
    })
})
```

Comment: oh whoops, typo. querySelector

Comment: A little explanation would make your answer better.